# Is this a constructor operator or conversion operator?

Tags: c++

```
class B
{
    public:
        operator B() const{ }    // What is this and what is the purpose?

    private:
        int m_i;
};
```

So the question is, is that a conversion operator or constructor operator and what is the use of it? Where to use it?

Comment: What is a "constructor operator"?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I didn't know that's why I asked. Why negative vote?

Comment: Giving 2 options to pick from in this context implies that both are valid options

Comment: @deepdive This site is for professional and enthusiast programmers. When you don't know something obvious, people get angry. (I've upvoted your question, as you couldn't know what it is, and Google doesn't say much).

Comment: @deepdive: The downvote came from me; I didn't spot that the two types are the same. I've taken it away now :)

Comment: @polkovnikov.ph Exactly my point. I couldn't find what it is called from either google or SO. This type of code fragment was mentioned in "Effective C++" so here I came to find answer

Comment: @deepdive Meyers can be stunning sometimes. Where exactly did you see that code?

Comment: It's a conversion operator. But it doesn't compile: https://ideone.com/vAI1ql.

Comment: @rwols Nope. Your error comes from cout... Add `using namespace std;`

Comment: @polkovnikov.ph: Ironically, this is not "obvious". :)

Comment: @rwols: See the example in my answer, which certainly does compile. Your example is broken due to a totally unrelated piece of logic (streaming to _stdout_ without the appropriate library headers included), which is a perfect example of why you must not randomly add arbitrary bits of unrelated code to a testcase.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Not as unobvious as overloading resolution rules for surrogate functions :) P.S. You're back to SO! Nice to see you again.

Comment: @deepdive oh ha, I think I need a break :-)

Comment: @rwols You must had a rough nite!! :)

Comment: I'm also curious, did you see this somewhere (in a Meyers book, really?) or is it your own invention?

Comment: How on earth is this "too broad"?!?!?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is a conversion function which will never be called implicitly. The Standard actually goes into some depth about this. 12.3.2/1:

> A conversion function is never used to convert a (possibly cv-qualified) object to the (possibly cv-qualified) same object type (or a reference to it), to a (possibly cv-qualified) base class of that type (or a reference to it), or to (possibly cv-qualified) void.

And in a footnote,

> These conversions are considered as standard conversions for the purposes of overload resolution (13.3.3.1, 13.3.3.1.4) and therefore initialization (8.5) and explicit casts (5.2.9). A conversion to void does not invoke any conversion function (5.2.9). Even though never directly called to perform a conversion, **such conversion functions can be declared and can potentially be reached through a call to a virtual conversion function in a base class.**

Also, conversion functions are still normal functions and can be called explicitly by name.

The note about virtual functions applies to code like this:

```
class B;

struct A {
    virtual operator B() const = 0;
};

struct B : A
{
    public:
        operator B() const{ return B(); } // virtual override

    private:
        int m_i;
};

A const & q = B(); // q has dynamic type B, static type A
B r = q; // Convert A to B using B::operator B()
```

Pedantic note: "conversion operator" is poor terminology. These are known as *conversion functions* and they are not considered to be a case of operator overloading, despite the `operator` keyword.

Comment: +1 for standard reference that I failed to find :( I'm stealing it, though. Sue me. :)

Comment: +1 for the example which demonstrates that it could be useful

Comment: s/useful/painful. If I traced into that in the debugger, I'd certainly do a double take. Then I'd get angry.

Comment: Yep another +1 if I could for the example. Good job. In fact, sod it, I'm deleting mine :)

Comment: I try to compile example, but I [get errors](http://pastebin.com/ajZUjdJe). Can you help me?

Comment: @Gluttton Sorry, I didn't test it. Just some minor things. Here you go: http://ideone.com/jN4FEo

Comment: Awesome, I love the irony of the warning made by clang++, `warning: conversion function converting 'B' to itself will never be used`

Comment: The standard uses "conversion function" and "conversion operator" interchangeably as far as I can tell. Is there some subtle difference or are you saying that those portions of the standard are using poor terminology? (Not a criticism, I just want to know what you're saying.)

Comment: @Praxeolitic The latest draft (N4296) only uses the phrase "conversion operator" twice: once to refer to `static_cast`, `const_cast`, `dynamic_cast` and `reinterpret_cast`, and once to refer to the particular conversion function of `std::vector<bool>::reference::operator bool`, which looks like an editorial error.

Answer (score 1):

It's a conversion operator. It allows you to cast an object of type `B` into an object of type `B`.

Comment: It seems weird that this is defined, and weirder that it doesn't do anything.

Comment: @Kieveli That doesn't even seem to be correct, as cast operator must return a value or throw an exception.

Comment: It's an conversion operator, not a "cast operator".

Comment: @Jefffrey `controversion operator` :)